# iPad doesn't rotate anymore

Tags: ipad, accelerometer

My iPad won't rotate the screen anymore when I turn it. It just happend (like all problems of course) without any cause.

I've done everything I can think of.

- Double tap on the Home button, swipe left and toggle the switch
- Toggle the switch on the left side of the iPad with 'rotation lock' set to on
- Reboot the iPad
- Restore the iPad

I'm out of options... Anyone with more options? Or is it hardware to blame?

Comment: Stand on your head? But seriously, what version of iOS and which generation iPad are you using?

Comment: Lol :-) it's an iPad 2 with iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Which orientation is it stuck in?

Comment: Did you restore from a backup, or was it a fresh restore?

Comment: @DanielLawson, it's stuck in portrait modus

Comment: @Nix, it's a fresh restore. With the brand new 5.1.1 software

Comment: The fact that it is still not working after a fresh restore, given all the other stuff you've tried, makes me think it is a hardware issue and there's something wrong with the accelerometer. I'd be inclined to take it to an Apple Store and let them have a look at it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've restored the iPad I would say that you've got some issue with the Hardware. If possible, Take it to an Apple Store for a Hardware test.

Using an app which requires the use of the Accelerometer may test it too.

**EDITED:** Its not the *Gyroscope* what tells the position of the device but the *Accelerometer*.

Comment: And app you can recommend?

Comment: Real Racing :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately, the iPad doesn't rotate at all anymore... Apple Store, here I come :) Thanks for your input!

Comment: Good luck with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and after a lot of other things thought I'd try one more thing, I ran the battery completely and let it sit for a day. Recharged it and its now working fine.

MY theory is that perhaps the accelerometer can become magnetized and running the battery out and allowing it to sit, dissipated the energy. Just a though, but it worked.

Comment: Complete battery drain worked for me too.. ; )