# Gyroscope in iPhone 4S doesn't work

Tags: backup, iphone, applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPad doesn’t rotate anymore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51747/ipad-doesnt-rotate-anymore)

I have a problem with my iPhone 4S. Its gyroscope doesn't work. But not at all. Sometimes it sets in vertical position and sometimes in horizontal. I read about it on the Apple's website and they suggest to make a back up and restore the initial settings. I've done this. At first everything was OK, gyroscope used to work. But then I started to restore all programs and at some moment I noticed that the gyroscope doesn't work again.

Maybe some app is the reason but I don't know which one. I hope the problem is in the software not in the hardware but...What I need to do? Maybe you faced the same problem?

Comment: Do you actually mean the gyroscope or the accelerometer? Because if it's just screen rotation that's stuck, that's controlled by the accelerometer not the gyroscope. How do gyroscope-controlled games (if you've got any) work?

Comment: The rotation software on iOS devices functions the same, so ill point this to another question that has better answers. Feel free to edit this more for Ask Different and we can reopen it if you need more specific help.

Answer (score 1):

Problems with the acceleration input can be faulty software (and usually it's some process going out of control and taking time away from the other tasks - not that it calculates up incorrectly), so that was a good first step to avoid telling you to seek hardware service.

At this point, unless you think the restore process was bad, it's almost entirely probable that the hardware is at fault and you'll need to take it in for repair.